# When running anaconda python from powershell, how do change the pager in "help"?

Tags: windows, anaconda

I am saddled with having to chase Anaconda Python around on Windows, where the cmd.exe command prompt is unusable and PowerShell is cmd.exe on amphetamines.

The pager in help() uses Windows "more" as the default pager, which is also unusable. I happen to have msys64 installed on this system: how do you coerse anaconda python to use a different pager, like msys64 "less" (since "less" is more more than "more")?

Answer (score 0):

As I continued to bang my head on the brick wall that Windows is, I came upon a solution.

Apparently, Anaconda Python in Windows honors the "PAGER" environment variable (although I was not able to located this in the docs for python on Windows). To set the environment variable in Windows so that Anaconda Python help() will use the msys64 "less" command, do the following:

```
set-item env:PAGER \msys64\usr\bin\less
```

Basically "set-item" is used to set something somewhere. "env" is the somewhere in this case: PowerShell apparently represents the environment as a separate "drive". "PAGER" would be the something. This syntax explicitly sets the environment variable "PAGER", although "pager" will work just as well (Windows addled lack of case dependence apparently reigns here as well). Just to check your new environment:

```
> get-item env: | \msys64\usr\bin\grep -i pager
PAGER                          \msys64\usr\bin\less
```

Maybe I saved some poor soul the hour of my life I will never get back...

Comment: Even better: 'set-item env:PAGER "\msys64\usr\bin\less -i -j24 -X"' which will ignore case, place the cursor on line 24 (middle of my large tty), and don't blank the screen on exit...